# Calling a custom cmdlet is not working?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm pretty new to powershell. I've built a custom cmdlet. I already have it registered in powershell but i wanted to test it before i started using the cmdlet. So i added a simple testapp to my solution. I'm trying to call my custom cmdlet like the following:

```
        var deploy = new DeployCommand();
        deploy.BranchDir = @"";
        deploy.DevDir = @"d:\sandbox\testdeploy";
        deploy.Invoke();
```

I set a break point in my cmdlet and when i execute .invoke it never does anything. The only method i'm overriding in my cmdlet is "ProcessRecord" but when i call invoke its never does anything. I'm sure its something simple. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling .Invoke() returns an IEnumerator ... you have to iterate it (e.g. call MoveNext()) in order for the cmdlet to actually get invoked. See the remarks on the [MSDN docs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568248%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jay. I knew it was something really simple. I appreciate your help.